# Compact Subsets Of Bounded Completely Monotonic Functions

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

A smooth function $f$ : $(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be completely monotonic, if $(-1)^nf^{(n)} \geq 0 $ $\forall n$. Let BCM denote the set of all bounded completely monotonic functions on $(0,\infty)$.

Consider the topology on $C^{\infty}(0,\infty)$ given by the separating family of continuous seminorms as follows:

for $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $p_{m,n}(f):=sup\{|f^{(k)}(x)|, x \in [1/n,n], 0 \leq k \leq m\}$. Therefore $C^{\infty}(0,\infty)$ is metrizable as the separating family of seminorms is countable.

Consider $K:=\{f \in BCM: f(0+) \leq 1\}$.

Then I need to show that $K$ and $ext(K)$ are compact sets, where $ext(K)$ is the set of all extreme points of $K$.

**My Progress:**
I've been able to show $ext(K) = \{e^{-\alpha x}, \alpha \in [0,\infty]\}$.

SInce $K$ and $ext(K)$ are subspaces of a metric space, in order to show that they are compact it suffices to show that they are sequentially compact. Any hint how to proceed from here?

Thank you in advance.